# R function `paste` is inverting the order of its arguments

Tags: r, string-concatenation

I am simply trying to print the output of a statistical process I'm running in R, and I find that the `paste` function appears to be inverting its inputs. Here's a MWE:

```
df = data.frame(p_values=c(0.01, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01))
min_index = which.min(df$p_values)
print(paste(str(min_index), 
            " with p-value ",
            str(df$p_values[min_index])))
```

I'm expecting output more-or-less like this:

```
2 with p-value 0.001
```

Instead, I'm getting the highly unintuitive result

```
 int 2
 num 0.001
[1] "  with p-value  "
```

In addition to the unexpected order of the printing, I'm getting the `int` and `num` and `[1]`, as well as not all being on one line.

What's going on here? I had thought `paste` was nearly a drop-in replacement for Python's concat operator `+`, but this result has me scratching my head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `str`ucture not `str`ing

`str()` in R is not the same as the Python [`str()`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_str.asp) function, which coerces an object to a string. In R, the [`str()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/str.html) function exists to:

> Compactly display the internal structure of an R object, a diagnostic function and an alternative to `summary` (and to some extent, `dput`).

This means when you do `str(min_index)`, R tells you that the structure of `min_index` is that it's an integer vector of length one, and the value of its element is 2.

The equivalent R function to Python's `str()` would be [`toString()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/toString.html), or perhaps [`as.character()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/character.html). However, in general R is more forgiving about types than Python. `paste()` and all other string concatenation or printing commands I can think of will coerce numbers to strings for you, so you can just do:

```r
paste(min_index, "with p-value", df$p_values[min_index])
# [1] "2  with p-value 0.001"
```

Note that I deleted your spaces, as by default [`paste()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html) adds one, though that can be changed by supplying a different `sep` argument or using `paste0()`.

### Why the output order seems inverted

Accounting for this, you might expect your output to be `"int 2  with p-value   num 0.001"`. However, it is:

```
 int 2
 num 0.001
[1] "  with p-value  "
```

This is because `str()` prints its output and returns nothing:

```r
x  <- str(1) # "num 1" is printed
print(x) # NULL
```

Your command can basically be interpreted as:

```r
str(min_index) # int 2
str(df$p_values[min_index]) # num 0.001
paste(NULL, "with p-value", NULL) # [1] " with p-value "
```

This why it prints in the order you see.

### A note on displaying output

As Onyambu says in the comments, if you want to display the output without the `[1]` you can use [`cat()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cat.html):

```r
cat(
  min_index, "with p-value", df$p_values[min_index],
  fill = TRUE
)
# 2 with p-value 0.001
```

Note that you need `fill = TRUE` to format this correctly, including a new line at the end. Depending on the purpose of your output, you may also want to look at [`message()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/message.html).

Comment: Consider using `cat` as OP is interested in display rather than combining the output. `cat` will also do away with the vector indexing `[1]`

Comment: `cat` is giving me a `NULL` at the end; why is that? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: you do not need to `paste` within cat. just `cat(min_index, "with p-value",...)` should work

Comment: Granted, `str` isn't the right function here, and in my own use I'm not sending its output into another function, but for completeness I'm curious if someone could explain what is happening that makes the output of `str()` always appear before any character strings that are sent into `paste`. Why isn't it appearing in order after coerced to character, and is there an underlying logic/rationale, or is it just "compatibility with S" (I imagine)?

Comment: @SamR Please include this last comment in your answer, and I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Why you are using str()? it returns the structure of the object.
if you use:

```
print(paste(min_index[1],"with p-value", df$p_values[min_index]))
```

it would work i think

Comment: Thank you for your answer. SamR kind of beat you to this answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

As another option you can consider `glue`

```
library(glue)
glue({min_index}, " with p-value ", {df$p_values[min_index]})
2 with p-value 0.001
```

Comment: Are the curly braces necessary? If so, this seems a less intuitive answer than the others. Thanks for your answer, though!

Comment: I get the same output without the curly braces. I think their value is more if you want to intersperse text and evaluated code, like `glue("{min_index} with p-value {df$p_values[min_index]}")`

Comment: @AdrianKeister in this case is not. But this is the way if want to the R code to be evaluated before being printed, see [glue documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glue/versions/1.7.0/topics/glue).